# python takes at most 2 arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on the simple `strategy` pattern implementation. I came to Python from Java world so I divided all classes to separate files as this seems ok for me. But I have troubles with packages and imports, please see the below code for details.

So I have a duck and 2 incapsulated behaviors: fly and quack.

Overall structure is:

```
behavior/
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
├── fly
│   ├── FlyBehavior.py
│   ├── FlyBehavior.pyc
│   ├── FlyNoWay.py
│   ├── FlyRocketPowered.py
│   ├── FlyRocketPowered.pyc
│   ├── FlyWithWings.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── FlyBehavior.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── FlyRocketPowered.cpython-37.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
└── quack
    ├── MuteQuack.py
    ├── Quack.py
    ├── QuackBehavior.py
    ├── Squeak.py
    └── __init__.py
duck
├── Duck.py
├── MallardDuck.py
├── ModelDuck.py
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── __pycache__
    ├── Duck.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── MallardDuck.cpython-37.pyc
    └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
MiniDuckSimulator.py
MiniDuckSimulator.pyc
```

**Fly classes:**

*FlyBehavior.py*

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class FlyBehavior(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def fly(self):
        pass
```

*FlyNoWay.py*

```
from behavior.fly import FlyBehavior

class FlyNoWay(FlyBehavior):

    def fly(self):
        print("I can't fly")
```

*FlyRocketPowered.py*

```
from behavior.fly import FlyBehavior

class FlyRocketPowered(FlyBehavior):

    def fly(self):
        print("I'm flying with a rocket")
```

*FlyWithWings.py*

```
from behavior.fly import FlyBehavior

class FlyWithWings(FlyBehavior):

    def fly(self):
        print("I'm flying!")
```

**Quack classes:**

*QuackBehavior.py*

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class QuackBehavior(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def quack(self):
        pass
```

*Quack.py*

```
from behavior.quack import QuackBehavior

class Quack(QuackBehavior):

    def quack(self):
        print('Quack')
```

*MuteQuack.py*

```
from behavior.quack import QuackBehavior

class MuteQuack(QuackBehavior):

    def quack(self):
        print('<< Silence >>')
```

*Squeak.py*

```
from behavior.quack import QuackBehavior

class Squeak(QuackBehavior):

    def quack(self):
        print('Squeak')
```

**Duck classes:**

*Duck.py*

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Duck(ABC):

    fly_behavior = None
    quack_behavior = None

    @abstractmethod
    def display(self):
        pass

    def perform_fly(self):
        self.fly_behavior.fly()

    def perform_quack(self):
        self.quack_behavior.quack()

    def swim(self):
        print('All ducks float, even decoys!')
```

*MallardDuck.py*

```
from duck import Duck

class MallardDuck(Duck):

    def __init__(self):
        self.quack_behavior = Quack()
        self.fly_behavior = FlyWithWings()

    def display(self):
        print("I'm a real Mallard duck")
```

*ModelDuck.py*

```
from duck import Duck

class ModelDuck(Duck):

    def __init__(self):
        self.fly_behavior = FlyNoWay()
        self.quack_behavior = Quack()

    def display(self):
        print("I'm a model duck")
```

**And main class:**

*MiniDuckSimulator.py*

```
from duck import MallardDuck
from duck import ModelDuck
import behavior.fly.FlyRocketPowered as FlyRocketPowered

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mallard = MallardDuck()
    mallard.display()
    mallard.perform_fly()
    mallard.perform_quack()

    model = ModelDuck()
    model.display()
    model.perform_fly()
    model.fly_behavior = FlyRocketPowered()
    model.perform_fly()
```

**Program output:**

```
$ python MiniDuckSimulator.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MiniDuckSimulator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from duck import MallardDuck
  File "/Users/p/Documents/Develop/patterns_book/00_strategy/py/duck/MallardDuck.py", line 3, in <module>
    class MallardDuck(Duck):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What's wrong with my modules? Is my approach for storing and structuring code/classes ok? Thanks.

Comment: `from duck.MallardDuck import MallardDuck`. But don't use CamelCase for module names in the first place. `from duck.mallardduck import MallardDuck` would have been better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
from duck.MallardDuck import MallardDuck
```

The `MallardDuck` you are importing is still a file, not a class, even though it has a single class in it.

Change all of your other imports in a similar manner.

some notes:

- strategy pattern is kind of useless in python, you can pass a function directly as an argument, instead of wrapping it in a class
- there's no reason to have a single class per file, use files to group relevant classes according to your judjement
- by convention, module (file) names are all lowercase, class names only are camelcase

Comment: Is this advice also applicable to the import statement within `MallardDuck.py`? Should `from duck import Duck` be something else instead?

Comment: @Kevin: yes, obviously for all imports of that type. I'll clarify it

Comment: @blue_note I changed my code and it works! Also, thanks for your notes, they are valuable. I'm also going to group classes and rename files.